# How to make the scale() function top priority?

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, scaling

I'm attempting to make a program that takes the information gathered from some calculations and plots it on a canvas graph. I need to scale the graph, however, so that it can accommodate larger numbers. But every time I put `ctx.scale();` the whole canvas blanks out! I thought I could stop this by scaling the canvas first, but nothing is drawn on the canvas after I scale it.

Here's the coding for my canvas:

```
var c=document.getElementById("graph_");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        graph_.style.backgroundColor="white";
        var z0=Math.max(Math.abs(a),Math.abs(b));
        var z=Math.round(z0);           
        var z1=Math.round(z);
        var z2=z*2
        // alert(z1);   
        // alert(z2);

        ctx.scale(3200/z,3200/z)    

        var xnew=360/2+360/2*a
        var ynew=360/2-360/2*b
        alert(xnew);    
        alert(ynew);

        ctx.font = '10px Calibri';
        ctx.fillText("( 0 , 0 )", 125, 85);
        ctx.fillText(z1, 210, 87);
        ctx.fillText(z2, 270, 87);

        ctx.fillText(z1*-1, 75, 87);
        ctx.fillText(z2*-1, 0, 87);

        ctx.fillText(z1, 120, 43.5);
        ctx.fillText(z2, 120, 10);

        ctx.fillText(z1*-1, 120, 120);
        ctx.fillText(z2*-1, 120, 145);

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(150, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 400);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.lineWidth = .2;
        ctx.moveTo(0, 75);
        ctx.lineTo(400, 75);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#8B8682";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth = 2;
          ctx.moveTo(xnew, 180);
          ctx.lineTo(180, ynew);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
          ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the stuff is being drawn to the canvas, you just can't see it because you're both too far zoomed in and still in the upper left corner of the graph since the default origin points for drawing are in the top left as 0,0.

So if you want to zoom in that far (even though you probably want to zoom out to show bigger numbers, i.e. larger drawings on the graph) you need to translate the canvas origin point to your new origin point (the top left of what you want to see) before you scale the context.

You can use the translate method like

```
ctx.translate(newX,newY);
```

But before you do you're going to what to save the context's state so you can revert back to it.

Say you wanted to zoom in on the center of the graph you would translate to the point that is:

```
ctx.translate((-c.width /2 * scale) + offsetX,(-c.height / 2 * scale) + offsetY);
```

where the offsetX is the canvas width / 2 and offsetY is the canvas height / 2 and the scale is by the amount that you're scaling in you ctx.scale call.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that scale zoomed it in! But I tried to use your code to translate my axis to the center, and it's not really working. I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Here's a link to the jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/Jeska/](http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/Jeska/). Should have the scales and offsets shown.

Comment: Okay, I checked out the site. Would I manually zoom it out now? I'm really new to Html5 and Javascript, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Yeah its no problem, although I do have to leave for a while after this so if I don't respond further you know. You can actually just grab the width and height right off your canvas variable, c in the case like c.width and c.height. And you're going to want to put the translate before the scale. I should have also mentioned earlier that offsetX and offsetY would be the point you want to zoom in on. In the examples case it was the center, or half the width and half the height.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `3200/z`, exactly?

I'm guessing that you are scaling your canvas by an enormous amount, so much so that the only thing visible on your screen would be the first few pixels of the canvas. Since you don't draw anything in the top-left 5 pixels of the screen, you don't see anything.

Comment: Z is the maximum of the y-intercept and x-intercept, which is then rounded up. So if the x-intercept was 10 and the y-intercept was 11, the y-intercept would be picked for Z. I got the dimensions of my canvas now, which was 320x320, and I multiplied it by 10 (scale 10 times).